# setContentView and Listeners

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm changing my ContentView of the Activity at some point. (to View2).
After changing it back to View1, the listeners are not more working.
I already tried putting the Listener in the onResume() method.

Is it common anyway to use setContentView() to display e.g. a Progress screen/please wait,...(while an asyncTask is running).
Or should you only have ONE mainView for each Activity? (and replacing the content dynamically).

//EDIT: To be more specific:
I am looking for something like

```
LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progress, null);
item.addView(child);
```

but instead of adding the "progress.xml", it should remove the current layout and ONLY show "progress.xml".
Do I need an "container" and show/hide mainView/progress?
But that doesn't seem very proper to me...

See also code below (stripped)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.view1);

       button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
}

setContentView(R.layout.view2);
[...]
setContentView(R.layout.view1);

//Listener not more working
```

Comment: How do you create 'button'? You need to show more code.

Comment: I think your approach is OK in some circumstances (e.g. view1 is a loading or splash screen and view2 is content. One way to handle this is to put the contents of view1 and view2 in the same layout file nested under a FrameLayout and switch the visibility of them from View.GONE to View.VISIBLE as necessary with View#setVisibility().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all, for your reply. You made me realize, the onClickListeners are getting lost when I remove or replace (using setContentView()) the main view. I ended up this way now:

onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.parse);
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null));
container.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progress, null));
```

onStartDoingSomething:

```
findViewById(R.id.dialog).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

onEndDoingSomehting:

```
findViewById(R.id.dialog).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I might change View.INVISIBLE to View.GONE, like nmr said, but since I have never used View.GONE, I have to check the Android doku first ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use 'findViewById' to initialize 'button', you would need to do that every time that you do setContentView(R.layout.view1);

Comment: thank's, you're right, that's the point I should call the listener Binders... but it's not very proper...

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one UI for each Activity, you should create another activity and in its onCreate method set the content view

Steps:

1. Create Activity
2. Use the following code to set the content View:

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.view2);

   }
3. Define the Activity in the applications manifest as such :
4. Create an intent in the first Activity:

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.view1);

   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               intent();
           }
       });
   }

   void intent(){

   Intent intent = new Intent();intent.setClass(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
   startActivity(intent);

   }

And there you go c:

Comment: Well, but more than one UI is working... but it seems that is a common thing to only call setContentView once in the onCreate mehtod and that's it. I can't go with two activities, wouldn't make sense here..

Comment: Changing activities isn't much of a hassle, but if its just a progress dialog that you want you can just create an progress dialog, have a look at this for reference veloper.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Comment: The thing is, that the Activity_XY is one of three Tabs. It starts an async tasks after pressing a button, that calls Progress-Handler-methods of the Activity_XY, providing it with some information (text).