# going back to previous layout makes the button stop working

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext, textview

I am testing my knowledge of android studio and seem to be running into a problem I am trying to make an app that takes the value of a edittext and puts that value into a textview when you click a button.  After that it brings you to a page with a back button on it and when I click that it brings me to the first page.  But when I try to click the first button it doesn't work anymore.

Code:

```
public class TestApp extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText ET;
private Button Add;
private TextView TV;
public String Array[] = new String[9999999];
private Button GoBack;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_app);
    ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET);
    Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String getC = ET.getText().toString();
            setContentView(R.layout.value);
            TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);
            GoBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GoBack);
            if (getC.length() > 0){
                for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++){
                    if (Array[i] == null){
                        Array[i] = getC;
                        TV.setText(Reminders[i]);
                    }
                }

            }

            GoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender_for_glasses);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setContentView and Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221647/setcontentview-and-listeners)

Answer (score 0):

If not necessary, don't modify the current content view. If you want multiple screens, you have to create multiple activities or fragments...

Moreover :

- at the beginning, you inflate `R.layout.activity_test_app`
- when you click on `goBack` button (1), you inflate `R.layout.activity_calender_for_glasses` and it's not the same as the first screen

(1) be careful to coding rules: https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/code-style